Android Studio GIF
My apps's build.gradle.kts file
I need your help. How to add gif if the dependencies in gradle is like this?
dependencies {
    implementation(libs.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.activity)
    implementation(libs.constraintlayout)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.ext.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.espresso.core)
}

I can't apply this implementation ‘pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.22’ in dependencies section.
I don't know if the problem is it was in a android studio version or whatever it is.

You are using Kotlin DSL for gradle files, implementation ‘pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.22’ is groovy syntax. You have to use kotlin syntax for *.kts files, add the dependency like this:
implementation("pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.22")

Or since you are using version catalog, you can put the dependency into your libs.versions.toml like this:
[versions]
#Add this to [versions] block
androidGifDrawable = "1.2.22" 

[libraries]
#Add this to your [libraries] block
android-gif-drawable = { module = "pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable", version.ref = "androidGifDrawable" }

And after gradle sync you will be able to add the dependency like this:
implementation(libs.android.gif.drawable)

